# Tasker Exported Apps Not Working

Tags: tasker

I have two Tasker projects that I would like to be able to share as stand alone apps. Project 1 turns Wifi On and Off based on location and Project 2 turns the screen on and off using the proximity sensor. I exported both separately (from my Samsung Galaxy Note 4 running stock 5.1.1) and sideloaded into my second device (Samsung Galaxy s5 running stock 5.0.0). Both apps install properly, display the correct required permissions, and display notifications (flash and popup) properly but will not effect the device in any other way. Project 1 will not change the Wifi state and Project 2 will not turn the screen off (using System Lock).

Has anyone experienced this before or can suggest why this might be occurring and what I might be able to do to solve it?

Comment: Share the XMLs of the both the projects (use an online code paste service to share). This "based on location" and "using the proximity senson" -- are they triggers or are they part of task, i.e.  are they actions? // Did you export into an app, a profile or a task only?

Comment: @Firelord, I will paste the code as soon as I am off work. The exported apps contain 1 profile and 2 tasks (an enter and an exit) apiece. The location and proximity sensing are done via the profiles.